# Find the Axis of rotation of rotation matrix $K$ after solving $(K-I)v=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, vectors, block-matrices

$$K=\
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
-1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Find the axis of rotation for the rotation matrix $K$.

This is from my previous thread [click here to view it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763829/find-the-axis-of-rotation-from-the-rotation-matrix)

Noting that the axis of rotation consists of vectors that remain unmoved. That is a vector $v$ satisfying  $Kv = v$. Or, $Kv - Iv=0$ where $I$ is the $3\times3$ identity matrix. For matrix $K$ after solving the homogeneous equations given by $(K-I)v=0$ and showing the working:

$(K-I)v=0$

So
$$K-I=\
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
-1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=\
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 1\\ 
-1 & -1 & 0\\ 
0 & -1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

therefore

$$\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 1\\ 
-1 & -1 & 0\\ 
0 & -1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}v=0$$

writing out the components for $v$ gives

$$\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 1\\ 
-1 & -1 & 0\\ 
0 & -1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ 
y \\ 
z 
\end{pmatrix}=0$$

Multiplying out gives three equations

$-x+z=0$

$-x-y=0$

$-y-z=0$

Now that i've done everything P Vanchinathan told me to do in the last thread, the question is how do i get the rotation axis from those 3 equations? As this method is time consuming, more importantly how would I get the answer by inspection?

Thank you to all that help and especially to P Vanchinathan in the last thread as if it wasn't for him I wouldn't have made it this far.

Regards, BLAZE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found that
$$
v=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}
$$
where
\begin{align*}
z&= x\\
y&=-x
\end{align*}
Hence the axis of rotation is given by the line
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\-x\\x
\end{bmatrix}=x\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}\quad x\in\Bbb R
$$
That is, the axis of rotation is
$$
\operatorname{Span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}
$$

Comment: thanks very much for your answer it really helped, do i have to get the solutions in terms of x? and what is Span please?

Comment: $\operatorname{Span}\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}=\{\lambda_1v_1+\dotsb+\lambda_nv_n: \lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n\in\Bbb R\}$ so in this case the axis of rotation is all scalar multiples of $(1,-1,1)$