# The linear map $ T: \mathbb R^3{\rightarrow} \mathbb R^3$ with given matrix is a rotation about some line. Find the line.

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Finals studying continued.

$ T: \mathbb R^3{\rightarrow} \mathbb R^3$ with matrix

$$A=  \begin{pmatrix}
-2/7 & 6/7 & 3/7 \\
 3/7 & -2/7 & 6/7 \\
6/7 & 3/7 & -2/7 \\
 \end{pmatrix} $$
relative to the standard ordered basis for $\mathbb R^3$ is a rotation about some line through the origin $ (0,0,0) $.

I figure that since it is a symmetric matrix, $A $is invertible and  $Q^{-1}AQ$ is diagonalizable. Also, $Q^{-1} = Q^{t} $ so I was thinking of finding the inverse of $A$. Or maybe try to find a vector that spans the line. I don't know.

EDIT: $A$ is not symmetric, so scratch that.

Comment: This matrix is not symmetrix... Also symmetric does not imply invertible.

Comment: It's not a symmetric matrix.  But it is diagonalizable.  One of the eigenvalues is $1$, so think about what happens to the corresponding eigenvector.  (The other two eigenvalues are probably complex numbers.  That's assuming that it really is an orthogonal matrix - I haven't check.)

Comment: There’s something wrong with the $(2,2)$-entry, probably should be $-2/7$.

Comment: Thanks, the teacher did indeed make a mistake in the prompt. It should be -2/7 and he had referred to it as a symmetric matrix, so I just assumed.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit:* <s>As Lubin points out in his/her comment, your matrix $A$ does not represent a rotation. One can easily see that $AA^T\ne I$ and $\det(A)\ne1$. The $(2,2)$-th entry is probably wrong and it may be $-2/7$.</s>

<s>If this is really the case,</s> it's not hard to see that all row sums of the corrected $A$ are equal to $1$. Therefore the axis of rotation is the line spanned by $x=(1,1,1)^T$ (because $Ax=x$).

In general, for a non-diagonal rotation matrix $A$, you can read off the axis from the skew-symmetric part of $A$ directly. See [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/767074/1551) to q766565 *"Find the axis of rotation of a rotation matrix by INSPECTION (NOT by solving $Kv=v$)*". In your example, the skew-symmetric part (up to a factor) of $A$ is equal to
$$
W=A-A^T=\frac37\pmatrix{0&1&-1\\ -1&0&1\\ 1&-1&0},
$$
therefore the rotation axis is the span of $(w_{23},w_{31},w_{12})^T$, which is the line spanned by $(1,1,1)^T$.

Comment: As I stated earlier, yes there was a mistake, I just forgot to change it. Thank you very much, I really appreciate the link.

Comment: This was actually very very helpful to my understanding of this concept. I had a giant misconception throughout this class. Thank you.